# Google Spreadsheet Secure Client Email Sharing?

Tags: python, google-api, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api, gspread

I am currently using Gspread python library to write data to a google spreadsheet.  However, the google spreadsheet is secure and I am unable to share the client email to write data to the spreadsheet.  Is there a work around to write data from my python script?  I am unable to change the configuration to make it sharable with anything.

Comment: see my comment in the answer below.

Comment: What do you mean by "google spreadsheet is secure", do you mean " 2-Step Verification"? Also "share the client email" share how?

Answer (score 0):

Scope: **spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/** email scope is not required

e.g.

```
   scopes = ["https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/"]
```

Sound like an OAuth2 issue - suggest you list the OAuth 2 scope settings you are using, but I think e-mail is not required

I think most example tend to include it, but don't think it is needed. This example is python, might help you, but it does include email https://github.com/eddyparkinson/gridspree

it has:

```
def login(force=True):
    next = request.args.get('next') or settings.SERVICE_URL
    scopes = ["https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/",
              "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me",
              "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
              "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly"]
    params = {
        'response_type':'code',
        'access_type':'offline',
        'state': next
    }

    if force:
        params.update(approval_prompt='force')

    authorization_url = get_auth_url(' '.join(scopes), **params)
```

Comment: question is very unclear but I doubt thats what he means. by email i think he means his google email account that he uses to log into his app. the spreadsheet is shared with him only.

Comment: @ZigMandel fair comment - the question is not clear on a few points.